# How can I ask for a clarification in an old question?

Tags: support, comments, questions, old-questions

How can I ask a clarification of a part of an old question that I don't understand?

For example:

I was reading this question

*[Best way to code Achievements system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192653/best-way-to-code-achievements-system)*

But, in the middle of the explanation there is a piece of code that I don't understand the reason for:

```
require '/badges/' . $file;
$badge = new $class;
```

I think that I could add a comment, but then it's probable that nobody will see my comment (as the question is old), and I'm not sure that is good idea create a new related question.

Comment: Adding a [bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on the question is a great way to draw attention to it.

Comment: If you add a comment, and if the asker is still around, he will get a notification about your comment, and might choose to answer. (Your particular question looks like not really like a question - most of it would be better in an answer, but there the same point would be valid.)