# Ask something related to (my own) old question

Tags: discussion, old-questions

Already asked here but has no answer yet: [How to ask for a clarification in a old question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105150/how-to-ask-for-a-clarification-in-a-old-question)

What should I do when I sudden meet a problem that related to the old answered question, create new question and link to the old one or something else? For (just) example, I ask 1 + 2 = ? and got the answer, then after 1 month, I need to know if 2 + 1 is the same or not.

Comment: I would hope you don't need to ask for either of those!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context is everything, but generally I would say that you should ask a new question and include a hyperlink to your old question for those who want to fully understand the history.

But it's equally important that your new question should be able to stand on it's own. I'd suggest it's poor practice to post a question like this:

> Following on from my other question (click here to view it), is it
>   also true that 2+1 is the same?

Rather, it'd be better to ask something like:

> I learned by asking a previous question (click here to view it) that 1+2 = x because blah blah blah. Is it also true that 2+1 = x? I think it might be because blah blah blah, but then agin blah blah blah. Can anyone clarify?